# Do bacteria with multiple flagella move faster than bacteria with a single flagella?

Tags: bacteriology

Do bacteria with multiple flagella move faster than bacteria with a single flagella? Assuming the flagella are at the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: in the following I'm going to focus on *E. coli*, which is the best understood system for bacterial flagellar movement. It would be interesting to compare uniflagellate bacteria and bacteria that have a fixed number of flagella. However, I know about *E. coli* and I think there is something interesting to be learned just from them, so I'll continue.

You're in luck that you asked this question when you did: [a very cool paper (1)](http://elifesciences.org/content/3/e01916#F12) was published just last year addressing your question. They find that the number of flagella has only a small effect on bacterial motion, but to understand why requires some background (A lot of the following background comes from this paper, which summarizes it pretty well).

I would argue that *E. coli* movement is one of the best-understood examples of cell movement we have, with excellent, high-resolution, quantitative data being generated for over 40 years now (the king in this field is Howard Berg at Harvard, if you want to learn more just read a recent review from him).

*E. coli* have a variable number of flagella, from one to ten or so. They operate in a bundle, but this bundle is highly dynamic due to the way *E. coli* moves. Rather than proceeding continually a straight line like a car, *E. coli* moves by a series of starts and stops called a [run-and-tumble](http://www.cellsalive.com/animabug.htm): the bacteria moves in a straight line for a *short* amount of time (a *run*), and then it stops in its tracks and changes direction (a *tumble*) before starting off again [(2)](http://jb.asm.org/content/182/10/2793.abstract). At a first pass this run-and-tumble behavior is essentially diffusion, the bacteria covers a lot of ground without going anywhere *on average* unless there's some food nearby, in which case the run-and-tumble is slightly biased so that the bacteria drifts toward the food.

As I said, during runs the flagella are bundled together and all turning counter-clockwise. A tumble happens when the bacteria sends a signal to the flagella to start turning clockwise. This breaks apart the flagellar bundle and sends all the flagella in different directions. Up until the paper I mention above, it was still not clear exactly how many flagella need to start turning clockwise before the bundle breaks up and a tumble commences.

Now you can see why having more flagella might not necessarily be a good thing: you might be able to move faster during the run (though this is not obvious to me, given the sometimes [unintuitive nature (3)](http://jilawww.colorado.edu/perkinsgroup/Purcell_life_at_low_reynolds_number.pdf) of [low-Reynolds number fluid dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number)) but at the same time the flagellar bundle will be more sensitive to break-up because with more flagella come more opportunities for one to start moving counter-clockwise and mess things up.

As the authors of the above paper [(1)](http://elifesciences.org/content/3/e01916#F12) find, it turns out that there are correlations between the actions of different flagella in a bundle, so that a bacteria with many flagella effectively acts like a bacteria with fewer flagella. The result is that the overall pattern of run-and-tumble is not much affected by the number of flagella; you might argue that number of flagella has a minor effect on bacterial movement.

On the other hand, you might be interested not in the net movement of a bacteria, but just on its speed when it's moving forward, in the run phase. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any good measurements of the run velocity of a bacterial cell as a function of number of flagella. But hopefully given this recent paper, maybe such measurements are on the horizon!

---

[(1)](http://elifesciences.org/content/3/e01916#F12) Mears PJ *et al.* (2014) Escherichia coli swimming is robust against variations in flagellar number. *eLife* 3:e01916.

[(2)](http://jb.asm.org/content/182/10/2793.abstract) Turner L *et al.* (2000). Real-time imaging of fluorescent flagellar filaments. *J. Bacteriol*. 182(10): 2793-2801

[(3)](http://jilawww.colorado.edu/perkinsgroup/Purcell_life_at_low_reynolds_number.pdf) Purcell EM. (1977). Life at low Reynolds number. *Am. J. Phys.* 45: 3-11.